# sqlite - SELECT COUNT(*how many times a value is stored*)

Tags: sqlite

I have a question and answers database set up. In the answers, a specific question will store a yes/no entry into the databse.

So my table has an "answer" column which will have the value "yes" or "no".

I want to be able to count how many times "yes" is stored and how many times "no" is stored.

So I could do this using two queries, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE answer="yes";
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE answer="no";
```

Is there any way I can do this in one query?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

group it:

```
select answer, count(*) from yourtable group by answer;
```

Comment: so how would I get the number of "yes"s and "no"s out of that?

Comment: would one row be yes's and the next be no's?

Comment: And of other things if there are "maybe", "probably", etc. You can add a where clause if those exist but you don't want them. You'll get the count for each one.

Comment: **And of other things if there are "maybe", "probably",....** Man, this is really a great comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT
sum(CASE WHEN answer="yes" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) countyes,
sum(CASE WHEN WHERE answer="no" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) countNO
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "yes answers", COUNT(*) WHERE answer="yes"
UNION 
SELECT "no answers", COUNT(*) WHERE answer="no";
```

Comment: `union all` may be better lest you risk an unnecessary duplicate-removal attempt - there's no possible crossover here.